# Flutter Web error TypeError: dart.global.firebase.analytics is not a function

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I am using a previously created firebase mobile application that is fully functioning with firebase at the mobile level, however, when I attempt to run it as a chrome page it doesn't seem to work, and when compiling triggers the error listed in the title. Flutter Doctor displays everything is working correctly and that chrome is a listed device. When attempting to build the web page a blank screen appears in a chrome window.

````
TypeError: dart.global.firebase.analytics is not a function
    at Object.analytics$ [as analytics] (http://localhost:59823/packages/firebase/src/top_level.dart.lib.js:114:102)
    at new firebase_analytics_web.FirebaseAnalyticsWeb.new (http://localhost:59823/packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart.lib.js:70:64)
    at Function.registerWith (http://localhost:59823/packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart.lib.js:29:82)
    at Object.registerPlugins (http://localhost:59823/packages/reminder_application/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:23:49)
    at main (http://localhost:59823/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:34:35)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59823/dart_sdk.js:39260:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59823/dart_sdk.js:39291:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:59823/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:33:18)
    at http://localhost:59823/main_module.bootstrap.js:19:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at window.$dartRunMain (http://localhost:59823/main_module.bootstrap.js:18:32)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
    at Object.runMain (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:8824:21)
    at http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22712:19
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3850:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11062:12)
    at Object._asyncStartSync (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:3814:20)
    at main__closure1.$call$body$main__closure (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22724:16)
    at main__closure1.call$1 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:22651:19)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary [as call$2$5] (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4184:16)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12435:39)
    at _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded$1$2 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12382:14)
    at _ControllerSubscription._sendData$1 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:11958:19)
    at _DelayedData.perform$1 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12147:59)
    at _PendingEvents_schedule_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:12196:14)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4022:24)
    at StaticClosure._startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:4028:11)
    at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:10931:9)
    at invokeClosure (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1258:26)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (http://localhost:59823/dwds/src/injected/client.js:1277:18)```
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web) for web installation before expecting it work.

Add the following to the `body` of your `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT]",
        storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT].appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "1:...:web:...",
        measurementId: "G-...",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
```

You need to add the script for each SDK you use. The above just shows the basics for analytics.